# Is the electric force really proportional to the charge it acts on?

Tags: electric-fields, quantum-electrodynamics

Of course we all know Coulomb's law, which includes the fact that the electric force experienced by an object is proportional to its charge. My question is: Does this hold to the best of our current knowledge, and not just in a classical approximation?

My thought is the following: In QED, electric forces are mediated by photons. So if *two* test charges $q_1,q_2$ interact with another charge $Q$, the interaction can be described by an interaction between $q_1$ and $Q$ and an interaction between $q_2$ and $Q$ (disregarding interactions between the test charges). The mediating photons do not interact in a first order approximation, so the interactions don't influence each other. Macroscopically this translates to a proportionality between electric force and charge. But to a higher order approximation, photons can interact, and I'm assuming that so can the mediating photons of the two interactions - that is, the interaction of multiple charges with another charge is more complex than each interaction by itself, even disregarding direct interactions of the two test charges. Could this lead to minor nonlinear effects on the electric force macroscopically?

Comment: Remember that in the standard model there are only three charges.  $+2/3, -1/3$ for quarks, $-1$ for leptons.  (ok, their opposite for antiparticles too.) So when you talk about arbitrary charges, these are composite systems, and the interactions only take place between their fundamental constituents.

Comment: The effects you are talking about are incredibly small and unlikely to show macroscopically, in fact only in the past three years did we observe light by light scattering in a bunch of data from LHC

Comment: Why are there three charges? Are you asking about three body forces, a la the strong force, or QED corrections to 1/r potential such as the Lamb shift or running of the fine structure constant, or strong field EM.?

Comment: Also if you are considering effects that arise from such small contributions....you don't really get to say that $q_1$ and $q_2$ don't affect one another. They will also contribute to each other's fields and thus you have, as JEB mentions, a three body system.

Comment: @JEB I'm asking about the latter.

Comment: @Triatticus Effects where the charges affect each other's fields, not just via superposition, would also be in the spirit of my question. The fact that such effects might be extremely small is not an issue. The mention of how it translates to macroscopic systems was more to justify me talking about forces than about the relevance for macroscopic measurements.